# PHP PDO - Pass dynamic string array to JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, string, forms, pdo

I have come to an understanding that the problem is that I am trying to pass a string array to a JavaScript.

I do not know how to proceed.

**FORM**

```
<input type="hidden" name="id">
<input type="hidden" name="adProd">
```

**DB Connection**

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT product_name, product_quantity, product_id FROM product ");
$stmt->execute();

// set the resulting array to associative
$result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

foreach ($result as $v) {
  echo "<td style='width:150px;border:1px solid black;'>";
  echo "</td>";
  echo '<tr>';
  echo '<td>' .$v->product_name. "</td>";
  echo '<td>' .$v->product_quantity. "</td>";
  echo '<td>' .$v->product_id.  "</td>";
```

**`product_id` below works exactly as it should.**

```
  echo '<td> <button type="submit" onclick="askForSell('.$v->product_id.')">  Sell  </button>  </td>';
```

**`product_name` on the other hand does not work.**

```
  echo '<td> <button type="submit" onclick="askForBuy('.$v->product_name.')">   Buy   </button> </td>';
```

**JavaScript**

```
form=document.getElementById("sellAndBuy");
```

**Works fine:**

```
function askForSell(id) {  
    form.action="sellProducts.php";
    form['id'].value = id;
    form.submit();
}
```

**Does not work:**

```
function askForBuy(adProd) {
    form.action="buyProducts.php";
    form['adProd'].value = adProd;
    form.submit();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the product name is a string, you need to have additional quotes around that name in the HTML. You'll need to escape those, since you already need to use both single and double quotes:

```
echo '<td> <button type="submit" onclick="askForBuy(\''.$v->product_name.'\')">   Buy   </button> </td>';
```

Note the `\'` that were added.

As these escaped quotes can become a pain in more complex situations, and also because it is better practice, you should consider binding event handlers with pure JavaScript code instead of using `onclick` HTML attributes.